# Custom Login with (or without) SSL vs OpenID

Tags: ssl, authentication, openid

I am currently building a custom forum *type* site for video games. Therefore, my audience would be anyone who likes video games (ie somewhat tech savvy).

The only sensitive information will be their login/email/password - no payments of any kind. AND The user will be required to have a **unique username**.

My Questions Are:

1) If I build a user login with their email/username & password, do I need to implement SSL?

2) Would OpenID be a better alternative to writing a custom login?

I know the whole custom login vs OpenID is a current ongoing debate, I was just looking for advice on my particular situation...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The short: Use a traditional login.

The long:

People understand traditional logins - people do NOT understand openid. Facebook connect cheapens your site and for the most part, so does twitter. So, use a traditional login. It's only the computer savvy that understand the notion of "saving you from yet another login".

Some people even think you (if incorporating OpenId) are gaining access to their *presonal top secret* gmail (openid account) information. They don't like that.

Incorporating openid seems simple at first, but beware - it is a nightmare. It is a monster that will only grow and grow.

So... don't use it, use a traditional login.

Comment: I agree with you partially. It is true some people would not prefer to login through their Facebook, or whatever account, but I think they should have that option. There are some people who are on it 2-4-7 and if that means not creating another account, then they are in.

Answer (score 0):

Well , I like video games but I don't like Open ID and have avoided using sites simply because they use Open ID. Seeing a login page without the usual username and password security on SO I just thought "WTF?" and don't, even now, like the idea of an 'Open' ID. An 'ID' is something that can be 'stolen', we're told many times - so having your ID made 'open' just sounds the same as making your ID 'really easily stealable'. Like having an open bank account. Now the tech behind it may be very safe, but you're asking me to take it on trust that the people who didn't think through the actual name of their product very smartly have been really, really smart and found a way to let my ID fly around multiple big social sites in perfect safety? Hmm...